# How change hamburger menu to regular?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

Last weekend i realised why u do mobile first. So itryed it for first time with some structure em and mediaq. But hamburger is to hard for me. How can i change hamburger menu to regular one
at @media screen and(min-width:960px)?
thank you

https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/gOxmeym

```
/*
 * And let's fade it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

p.s clarification
once 960px screen reached
[hamburger transforms into desktop menu like we see at sektop versions](https://www.creativosonline.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/lavalamp.jpg.webp)

Comment: ** hamburger menu to regular one** what do you mean by that

Comment: hambuger menu to usual ul li menu *Link Link LInk LInk*

Comment: This question is less likely to get answers until you add some details or pics of behavior of what you wanted to achieve

Comment: never thought that i'm so unclear

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: look a really have no idea how describe the issue only the target. i simply copied hamburger code and changed the width. and dunno how to adapt in to bigger sizes. that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your markup is wrong you shouldn't use like this :

```
<ul id="menu">
   <a href="#"><li></li></a>
   <a href="#"><li></li></a>   
</ul>
```

It must be like this :

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

> Below snippet is with minimum code to give you a start . You can explore many areas within it and style according to need . Also JavaScript can be the option to toggle the menu on smaller screens .

Here used `@media` for screen sizes with `max-width: 960px` once that condition is satisfied the horizontal menu will convert into a vertical one and a checkbox(harmburger-icon) will appear . By using CSS you can toggle `display: none`(or any other functionality like opacity or coming from the left ....any)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  input {
    display: block;
  }
  input:checked+ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ideas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks.see it's working and still can't get it to work on my page/meh

Comment: Use `media` for smaller screen sizes @DeanWinchester88

Comment: https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/gOxmeym as i go from mobile to bigger.basically i need  to change max-width to min-width and swap properties u wrote. doesn't works/ gosh struggling with such simple task

Comment: https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/gOxmeym that is maximum i could get by recoding

Comment: What is the problem you are facing in above code pen . It looks fine to me

Comment: https://youtu.be/ydZc17rlR5E timestamp @7.00 this is how it should work in pen above

Comment: Put this in your `min-width: 960px` or whichever you prefer : `#menu{transform: translate(0, 0);}`